# Issue loading chart.js zoom plugin with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I'm trying to use the [chart.js zoom plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom) with my Qlik Sense extensions. Qlik is not really relevent here I guess but I will mention it anyways.

So here is how I try to load the plugin via require.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        chart: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min",
        datalabels: "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.3.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min",
        zoom: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/0.6.3/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min"
    },
    map: {
        datalabels: {
            "chart.js": "chart"
        },
        zoom: {
            "chart.js": "chart"
        }
    }
});
```

I had a similar issue with the datalabels plugin, but it was solved by the mapping in the above code snippet.

The error I always keep getting is

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined**

This is coming from line 11 [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/blob/master/src/chart.zoom.js) .

Any help on how should I require this plugin to overcome this error? I have tried to search for a solution with no luck so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error. I'm not yet sure where it comes from...

Answer (score 1):

We also had a similar issue.  We had tried endlessly to attempt the owners solutions however to no avail.  Please see this issue and let me know about your findings: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/issues/73.

The issue occurs since RequireJS expects libraries to omit `.js` and therefore the Module ID `chart.js` will not load appropriately.

Regarding the error on line 11, we also replicated that issue and our conclusion was that chart was not loaded correctly.

Comment: Did you happen to find any workaround for this? In the github issue you mentioned that renaming chart.js to chartjs fixed it, is this the case?

Comment: That "fix" is what allowed us to load the library.  It then failed on the exact error you linked here (line 11: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined`).  Unfortunately I have put this plugin usage aside due to the amount of time devoted to get it to work to no avail.  With that said, I would be more than glad to help find out what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, I personally just don't too good knowledge about requireJS so I am pretty limited to get help from the owners or here :-/.